# return a json from my html page

Tags: html, json

I have created a HTML code to build an user form that will contain information that people write inside the texts. This page also has a button that should take all the entered information and convert it into a json file.

I have never done this before, so I have no idea how I can do that. As far as I read, I understand that I need a local server to send the html code to it so it can return the json, but the process to do this is absolutely unclear for me.

My code in html is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <header>
   <h1>My Promo</h1>
   <h2>Get insights out of an endless see of data...</h2>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css">
 </header>

 <form action="http://localhost/" method="post">

  <!-- Input label -->
  <div class="formgroup" id="name-form">
    <label for="name">What is your banner?*</label>
    <input type="text" name="banner" />
  </div>

  <!-- Input label -->
  <div class="formgroup" id="name-form">
    <label for="name">Name of current promo*</label>
    <p>(write a short name, e.g: "DPE17")</p>
    <input type="text" name="CurrentPromo" />
  </div>

  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Get my data" />
  </div>

 </form>
</html>
```

Then, when I click on the button "Get my data" it does nothing.

Can you give me the process to capture the json from this?

Many thanks!

Comment: you need a server side language to do so, like php [see this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Answer (score 1):

As you did not mention any specific JSON structure I think below code will work for you. You will have to customize based on your needs.

I will recommend you to find and check different javascript libraries and see what suits you best for your client side application.(jQuery is easiest to learn)

Also check if it is a REST server. Based on that decide on your client side javascript framework. (Angular is good choice for REST based applications)

```js
function onSubmitForm( myForm ){
  var formjson = JSON.stringify( $(myForm).serializeArray() ); //  <-----------

  console.log( formjson );
  return false; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <h1>My Promo</h1>
    <h2>Get insights out of an endless see of data...</h2>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css">
</header>

<form action="http://localhost/" method="post" class="myform" onsubmit='return onSubmitForm(this)'>

<!-- Input label -->
<div class="formgroup" id="name-form">
    <label for="name">What is your banner?*</label>
    <input type="text" name="banner" />
</div>

<!-- Input label -->
<div class="formgroup" id="name-form">
    <label for="name">Name of current promo*</label>
    <p>(write a short name, e.g: "DPE17")</p>
    <input type="text" name="CurrentPromo" />
</div>

<div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Get my data" />
</div>

</form>
</html>
```

Comment: where am I supposed to insert the onSubmitForm function? I run the code you sent in my pc and the server threw a HTTP Error 405

Comment: Create a javascript file and include in your HTML code. Check this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp